# How to send hidden field in email?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some reference number that i need to send in mail but to be hidden or at least less noticeable, so if user reply on that mail that i still have that reference number.

I tried this:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .mail {
    font-family: RobotoRegular;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
    opacity: 0!important;
    color: transparent!important;
    font-size: 0!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    width: 0!important;
    height: 0!important;
  }
</style>
```

Also added in span directly:

```
<span class="mail" style="font-family:RobotoRegular;background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);opacity:0!important;color:transparent!important;font-size:0!important;overflow:hidden!important;width:0!important;height:0!important;">#REF' + this.id + '# </span>
```

But without success.Font size is not changing. Any suggestion how can i achive this?

Comment: Put it in the subject like anyone else.

Comment: i agree, customer can call you and give you that number it's just easier, and it's looks professionnal. But in any case i tested you span and it's not visible at all, so what is the issue ?

Comment: issue is when i send mail and client open in outlook for example its visible

Comment: As it should be. I have this in all my help requests.
`Help needed to do x,y,z. (REF:1233213)`  or have the ref first then you can sort

Comment: @Mplungjan ok if its shoud be visible, can i then change font size of that span or font family ? Because right now its is larger than other text in email?

Comment: i tested it and its invisible in thunderbird and gmail, don't know about outlook, some mail clients might disable css also

Comment: Email clients simply aren't standardised and predictable enough for this. Some may even turn your entire mail into plaintext without any styling whatsoever.

Comment: You might put your ref as a data attribute `<div data-ref="my-ref"/>` it will not be displayed by any mail client because it's not text, and you don't need any styling to hide it

Comment: If you put it in the SUBJECT line, then it will have the same size as the other text in the subject

Comment: @Lk77, Inline styes for Outlook and even those can be deactivated.

Comment: How can the user provide you the reference number if the user can not see it? Put it in the subject or add a "this is you reference number xyz", like @mplungjan suggested.

Comment: That reference number is not important for user its just for me to know how to recognize that specific user. So user does not need to know that number, so thats why i dont want to send it in subject. Its not important